# Dynamically create variable names and values using paste in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a dataset with a bunch of survey questions, many of which have subquestions. It looks like this:

[image]

```
structure(list(Q1 = c(1, 2, 2), Q2 = c(2, 3, 1), Q3a = c("a", 
"a", "c"), Q3b = c("b", "b", "d"), Q3c = c("c", "c", "e"), Q4a = c("a", 
"a", "c"), Q4b = c("b", "b", "d"), Q4c = c("c", "c", "e"), Q4d = c("d", 
"d", "f"), Q5 = c("e", "f", "g")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Basically for each of the columns that fits the pattern "Q[0-9]+[a-z]", I want to create a new column with that question number, where the values are all values from the subquestions pasted together in a string. I know I can do this manually, but there are a number of questions so if there is a way to do this programmatically I would appreciate it. Desired output is:

[image]

```
structure(list(Q1 = c(1, 2, 2), Q2 = c(2, 3, 1), Q3a = c("a", 
"a", "c"), Q3b = c("b", "b", "d"), Q3c = c("c", "c", "e"), Q4a = c("a", 
"a", "c"), Q4b = c("b", "b", "d"), Q4c = c("c", "c", "e"), Q4d = c("d", 
"d", "f"), Q5 = c("e", "f", "g"), Q3 = c("a, b, c", "a, b, c", 
"c, d, e"), Q4 = c("a, b, c, d", "a, b, c, d", "c, d, e, f")), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Just added the data - thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `tidyverse` you could do the following. After selecting Q1 through Q5 (the columns needed to reproduce the new columns and omitting the already desired Q3 and Q4), you can put the data frame into long format (often preferable for future analyses). Row numbers `rn` are assigned to track rows, and all columns are made `character` so can be combined.

When in long format, the items sharing the same number (e.g., Q3a, Q3b, etc.) are grouped and then summarised, putting multiple values of the same group together separated by commas. Then, to get to your desired wide data frame, you can use `pivot_wider`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  select(Q1:Q5) %>%
  mutate_all(as.character) %>%
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -rn, 
               names_to = c("item", "subitem"), 
               names_pattern = "Q(\\d+)(\\w*)") %>%
  group_by(rn, item) %>%
  summarise(value = toString(value)) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = rn, 
              names_from = item, 
              values_from = value, names_prefix = "Q") %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-rn)
```

**Output**

```
  Q1    Q2    Q3      Q4         Q5   
  <chr> <chr> <chr>   <chr>      <chr>
1 1     2     a, b, c a, b, c, d e    
2 2     3     a, b, c a, b, c, d f    
3 2     1     c, d, e c, d, e, f g
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `grep` to identify the columns and use it in `split.default` to create list of similarly named columns. We can `paste` the values rowwise for each element in list.

```
cols <- grep("Q[0-9]+[a-z]", names(df), value = TRUE)

cbind(df, sapply(split.default(df[cols], sub('(Q\\d+).*', '\\1', cols)), 
          function(p) do.call(paste, c(p, sep = ','))))

#  Q1 Q2 Q3a Q3b Q3c Q4a Q4b Q4c Q4d Q5    Q3      Q4
#1  1  2   a   b   c   a   b   c   d  e a,b,c a,b,c,d
#2  2  3   a   b   c   a   b   c   d  f a,b,c a,b,c,d
#3  2  1   c   d   e   c   d   e   f  g c,d,e c,d,e,f
```